# Distribution of the prime numbers.

Tags: statistics, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Suppose we fix a quantity $x\geqslant 0$, and consider the set 
$$
P(x) = \left\{\frac{p}{\pi(x)} : p\leqslant x \text{ prime}\right\} \subset[0,1] .
$$
As $x\to \infty$, it seems like the $P(x)$ are converging to a measure. Here are a couple histograms:
[image: Primes at most 100 000]
(Primes $\leqslant 10^5$.)
[image: Primes at most 10 000 000 000]
(Primes $\leqslant 10^{10}$.)

> Is the limiting distribution known? That is, can these pictures be made rigorous in a reasonable way and proven (possibly assuming the Riemann Hypothesis?)

**Edit:** here is a more precise statement.

For a real number $x$, let $P_x = \frac{1}{\pi(x)} \sum_{p\leqslant x} \delta_{p/x}$. This is a discrete measure supported on the interval $[0,1]$. I claim that 
$$
P_x \approx \frac{x}{\mathrm{Li}(x)\log(t x)}\, \mathrm{d} t 
$$
in the sense that if $L_x$ denotes the second measure and 
$$
D(P_x,L_x) = \sup_{0\leqslant t \leqslant 1} \left| P_x[0,t] - L_x[0,t]\right| = \sup_{0\leqslant t \leqslant 1} \left| \frac{\# \{p\leqslant x : p\leqslant t x\}}{\pi(x)} - \frac{\mathrm{Li}(t x)}{\mathrm{Li}(x)}\right|
$$
is the discrepancy (Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic), then $D(P_x,L_x) \ll x^{-\frac 1 2+\epsilon}$.

> Is this claim known to be equivalent to the Riemann Hypothesis?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean with "converging to a measure". Do you mean if $f(x)$ is Riemann integrable on $[0,1]$ then $\lim_{x \to \infty}\frac{1}{\pi(x)}\sum_{p < x} f(\frac{p}{\pi(x)})$ converges to $\int_0^1 f(x) \varphi(x)dx$ for some $\varphi$ ? In that case use the prime number theorem : $p_n \sim n \ln n$ and $\pi(x) \sim \frac{x}{\ln x}$

Comment: As I wrote, all you need is the prime number theorem : $p_n \sim n \ln n$ and $\pi(x) \sim x / \ln x$. Now for measuring how fast it converges, yes it depends on $\zeta(s)$'s zero-free region and the Riemann hypothesis. Yes what you wrote at the end is obviously equivalent to the Riemann hypothesis.

Comment: @reuns Hello,I'm interesting in your problem,but I'm too ignorant to prove it.I guess$\lim \frac{1}{\pi(x)}\sum_{p\le x}f(\frac{p}{x})=\int_0^1f(x)dx$,could you give me more hint or answer?Thanks!